# How to add translations for new words in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation

I'm using English, Spanish and German as three store views for my site. What is the easiest way to add translations for new words?

Even if I add new words with the translations it doesn't show in the frontend.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

For this:

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Text here');?>
```

Add like:

> app/locale/{lang_ISO}/Mage_Catalog.csv

```
"Text here","Translation here"
```

For this:

```
<?php echo $this->__('Text here'); ?>
```

Or this (in theme `local.xml`, note the `translate` attribute; also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8408058/794071):

```
<reference name="top.links">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
        <label>Text here</label>
        <title>Text here</title>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Add like:

> app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/locale/{lang_ISO}/translate.csv

```
"Text here","Translation here"
```

E.g.: in your theme folder:

> /locale/fr_FR/translate.csv

```
"Inspiration","Your France Translation"
```

Comment: Also, the {lang_ISO} depends on the default language you set up for your store in System > Configuration > General > Localization options > Locale profile.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really translate words. You need to translate static blocks, pages, attributes, e-mail templates and configuration related elements from the backend. To translate system strings, there's `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme]/locale/{locale}/translate.csv`

{locale} could be for example de_DE for the German language used in Germany.

Modification of translation files at `app/locale/{locale}/` is NOT advised as they are part of language packages and should be regarded as core elements that may get overwritten as soon as the package is updated.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in these easy steps.
Step 1: Create new store view.
By admin of our store go to STORES->Settings->All stores.
`Create Store View`. Select store and give name for example Hindi.
Go to STORES->Settings->Configuration.
At the top-left corner in `Store View` Select  your store view `Hindi`.
In `General` tab `Locale Option` Select `Hindi(India)` from the Dropdown.

Step 2: Set your theme to this Store view. 
From admin Go to CONTENT->Design->Configuration `Edit` your Store view and set the theme.

Step 3:Create csv file in `<magento dir>/app/design/frontend/<vendorName>/<themeName>/i18n/hi_IN.csv` (hi_IN for Hindi).
Contents are:

`"Sign In", "Your Text"
"My Account","Your Text"
"My Wish List", "Your Text"`

Step 4:Deploy the content.
in magento directory of your terminal
`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_US hi_IN`
Clean the cache and refresh the page.
After switching to new store view your changes will be showing.
This will work for magento 2.2.x

Answer (score 0):

> What is the easiest way to add translations for new words?

I guess the *tech* part is answered ... :)

To make it "easy" - or to speed up l18n - you can automatically translate `CSV` files.

This may be useful if you have installed or built an extension that has only `en_US.csv` included.

**Req:**

- https://github.com/chriskonnertz/DeepLy

  ```
  composer require chriskonnertz/deeply
  ```
- add `CSV` to translate
- add simple PHP script

  ```
  <?php
  require 'vendor/autoload.php';

  use ChrisKonnertz\DeepLy\DeepLy;

  $deepLy = new DeepLy();

  $read = fopen('en_US.csv','r');
  $write = fopen('de_DE.csv','w');

  while (($data = fgetcsv($read, 0, ",")) !== false) {
      $data[1] = $deepLy->translate($data[0], 'DE', 'EN');
      echo "From: " . $data[0] . "\n";
      echo "To: " . $data[1] . "\n";
      fputcsv($write, $data);
  }
  fclose($read);
  fclose($write);
  ```

Not really nice, but it works ... :P

---

#### Notes

- this package uses an (undocumented?) API, that requires no AUTH key. There seems to be a threshold, but it's untested
- for developer access, there is a paid APIv2 ([5€/month](https://www.deepl.com/pro.html))
- supports DE, EN, ES, FR, IT, NL, PL, auto-detect

<sup>I'm not related to *deeply*, it just saved me a couple of hours ... sorry for advertising.</sup>