# Custom translate.csv file not loading

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, localisation, package

I created a new package/theme/skin from scratch in Magento 1.9.1.

The theme and skin load fine. I tried adding translations and cannot get them to load. All cache settings are disabled.

I've added the CSV file here:

`/app/design/frontend/{my_package}/{my_theme}/locale/en_US/translate.csv`

translate.csv:

```
"testing123","Translation Worked"
```

header.phtml

```
<?= $this->__('testing123') ?>
```

I added `{my_theme}`, which for me is named "responsive" to the admin at the :

[image: Theme setup]

The result is the header displaying 'testing123' instead of the translated 'Translation Worked'. What have I missed? How do I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that I hadn't yet set my custom theme as the default in the admin under **System->Design->Add Design Change**.

Answer (score 1):

translate.csv should be inside the language you want to translate not in the default language.

Please refer this link:
[How to add translations for new words in Magento?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/23677/how-to-add-translations-for-new-words-in-magento)