# how can i customize the message inside addError('text');

Tags: error, localisation

i have a function like this

```
public function triggerErrorMessage()
{
    $sessionCheckout = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
    $sessionCheckout->addError('An error occurred during your transaction.');
}
```

how can i customize the text "An error occurred during your transaction" without changing the code, is this translateable in locale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For magento version 1

You have to add your text in

**/app/design/frontend/{my_package}/{my_theme}/locale/en_US/translate.csv**

original text,changed text

More info [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/23677/how-to-add-translations-for-new-words-in-magento)

you can add code as below:

```
$sessionCheckout->addError($this->__('An error occurred during your transaction.'));
```

Comment: Does it work with addError seeing as the string doesn't have localisation on it?

Comment: Updated answer check it

Answer (score 1):

No, these are not translated by default. If you search for "addError" in the core code, you will find that they always pass a translated string to the method.

If the code you showed comes from an extension, the developers apparently did not care too much about translation. You will have to change the code.