# Make Magento aware of new translations csv files

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation

My translations work as long as I copy/paste an existing Mage_*.csv file into my `locale/{lang}/` folder. From there, I can delete what I don't want to override, add new text to work with my modules, etc.

I want to add my own file, like `translations.csv` and have it just pull from there. How do I make Magento 1.9 aware of this file? I'd like to have module-specific csv files to keep things separated, like `PackageName_ModuleName.csv`, and all my translations for that particular module live in that file.

Thanks!

Comment: refer http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/23679/45103

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was missing this:

```
<translate>
    <modules>
         <PackageName_ModuleName>
             <files>
                 <default>PackageName_ModuleName.csv</default>
             </files>
        </PackageName_ModuleName >
   </modules>
</translate>
```

It needed to be added to my `config.xml` file for my module under the `<frontend>` tag.