# Translation of Magento (Frontend) v1.9.2.4 to Serbian

Tags: localisation, translate

I have to translate Magento frontend to Serbian. How can I do that and where can I find the translation files? I am guessing I have to just put them in locale/sr_SR.csv, but not really sure. Neko zna o ovome kako se radi? :)

Comment: see this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/23677/how-to-add-translations-for-new-words-in-magento

Answer (score 1):

First Please check your file of the need to translated word format

it should be in

```
<?php echo $this->__('Word') ?>
```

if it doesn't work please use below steps

I have created a file to translate English to German

Create folder path for language file

```
app\design\frontend\<theme>\default\locale\de_DE
```

file name

```
translate.csv
```

Here `de_DE` folder for German language

Inside the csv file should be

[image]

And The world which is translated in phtml format is

```
<?php echo $this->__('word') ?>
```

Hope this will work..